# MYSQL function parameter not working on internal select

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a function that has a SELECT inside another SELECT.
When i try to use one of the function parameters as part of the internal SELECT it returns nothing.

```
FUNCTION `nota_alumno`(`uid` VARCHAR(255), `total_p` INT) RETURNS float
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT (SUM(n_pregunta)*10)/total_p  AS nota
       FROM
       (SELECT nota_pregunta(scores.userid,question) as n_pregunta  FROM `scores` WHERE scores.userid=uid GROUP BY question) as T);
END
```

It does work when i just put a non parameter-based value:

```
FUNCTION `nota_alumno`(`uid` VARCHAR(255), `total_p` INT) RETURNS float
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT (SUM(n_pregunta)*10)/total_p  AS nota
       FROM
       (SELECT nota_pregunta(scores.userid,question) as n_pregunta  FROM `scores` WHERE scores.userid="ddj239dkdsd" GROUP BY question) as T);
END
```

For reference as requested, here is the definition of the function nota_pregunta:

```
FUNCTION `nota_pregunta`(`userid` VARCHAR(255), `q` INT) RETURNS float
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT ROUND(1/COUNT(*),2) FROM `scores` WHERE userid=userid and question=q);
END
```

Comment: To debug this add an insert to a debug table and see if you are actually passing a value to the uid parameter. - Still got problem add sample data and expected output as text.

Comment: And the function nota_pregunta

Comment: added the function @P.Salmon

Comment: I tried the insert debugging and it does pass the parameter, but still doesn't work in the select @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is excess. BEGIN_END is excess too.

```sql
FUNCTION nota_alumno(uid VARCHAR(255), total_p INT) 
RETURNS float
RETURN ( SELECT SUM(nota_pregunta(userid, question)) * 10 / total_p  AS nota
         FROM scores 
         WHERE scores.userid=uid 
         GROUP BY question
         );
```

Also the finction `nota_pregunta` is not correct (in `WHERE userid=userid` you compare parameter and parameter, i.e. you check that provided `userid` is not NULL), must be

```sql
FUNCTION nota_pregunta(userid VARCHAR(255), q INT) 
RETURNS float
RETURN ( SELECT ROUND(1/COUNT(*),2) 
         FROM scores 
         WHERE scores.userid=userid AND question=q);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Let me explain the subquery. In the scores table there's multiple rows with the same "question" value so I do need to first get the count of all matches with same userid and question, otherwise I don't get the desired results.

Comment: *otherwise I don't get the desired results.* ?? Provide a sample which shows the output incorrectness. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: Well, I don't get any results with my initial problem, but I don't think I need to put the results on the changes you suggested basically removing parts of my function wich are out of the question being asked. You just assumed part of my querys where unnecesary not mentioning why you would assume they are "excess".